# Maintain latest 5 users in Array Android Java?

Tags: java, android, arrays, sorting

i am trying to maintain latest 5 users in array in Android app. such that if sixth new login happen then it save in array but the first login of array lost let me show example

```
Array
0-tom
1-chris
2-john
3-stark
4-jain
```

above are five login in application,

if i login sixth time with jeena then array would be,

```
Array
0-chris
1-john
2-stark
3-jain
4-jeena
```

How would i do this hopes for your suggestion

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: with a queue... study first "queues in java"

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `Queue` in `java.util.Collections`.

Sample Code:

```
Queue<String> users = new LinkedList<String>();
//Add elements in the Queue using add() method.
users.add("Tom");
users.add("Chris");
users.add("John");
//You can remove the first element in the Queue using remove() method.
users.remove(); //Removes Tom and {"Chris","John"} left in Queue.
```

See [Java Queues](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

One of the way is to use queue to achieve this(more details [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html))

```
Queue<String> qe=new LinkedList<String>();
    qe.add("a");
    qe.add("b");
    qe.add("c");
    qe.add("d");
    qe.add("e");
```

Use **poll()** to remove the elements from  the end of the queque

```
    qe.poll());
```